# Ao tentar definir coluna como Unique, erro é gerado falando de 767 bytes

Tags: mysql, laravel, xampp, mariadb

Quando tento executar uma migration no Laravel, o seguinte erro é gerado:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General
>   error: 1709 Index column size too large. The maximum column size is
>   767 bytes. (SQ   L: alter table `usuarios` add unique
>   `usuarios_email_unique`(`email`))
>
> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1709 Index column
>   size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes.

A sql que está sendo executada é essa:

```
create table `usuarios` ( 
  `id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, 
  `nome` varchar(255) not null, 
  `email` varchar(255) not null, 
  `password` varchar(255) not null, 
  `nivel_id` int unsigned not null, 
  `empresa_id` int unsigned not null, 
  `departamento_id` int unsigned null, 
  `cargo_id` int unsigned null, 
  `status` tinyint(1) not null default '1', 
  `created_at` timestamp null, 
  `updated_at` timestamp null) 
default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci

alter table `usuarios` add unique `usuarios_email_unique`(`email`)

alter table `usuarios` add index `usuarios_password_index`(`password`)
```

O que pode estar gerando isso?

Comment: São as configurações do MySQL, eu também estava com esse problema e resolvi através desse link, veja se te ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42043205/how-to-fix-mysql-index-column-size-too-large-laravel-migrate

Comment: Isso acontece porque o email esta com o tamanho muito grande não aceitando criar o índice.unico. Solução diminiu o tamanho de 255 para 100 vai funcionar acho também um exagero 255

Comment: @arllondias assim funcionou kkkkk, eu só troquei o charset da conexão e funcionou corretamente

Answer (score 2):

Resumindo as colunas do tipo `string` do `Laravel` vem com default 255 o que faz com que o tamanho exceda ao tamnho maxímo para o indíce, vá até sua `migration` e troque o `lenght` do campo com chave `unique` para 191 ou para o tamanho que preferir, por exemplo:

`$table->string('email', ['length' => 191])->unique();`

Você pode adicionar no seu arquivo `AppServiceProvider.php` dentro do método `boot()` a seguinte instrução para seu campo `string` ficar `default` e não precisar declarar em toda `migration` o tamanho do campo string:

`Schema::defaultStringLength(191)`;

Comment: Não é uma boa ideia, na minha opinião. O campo "password" também está dando esse mesmo problema, e creio que o hash gerado pode passar esse tamanho...

Comment: Não passa de 191, tenho algumas aplicações em Laravel e definimos o default de string para esse tamanho justamente para não dar brecha para erros futros

Comment: @WallaceMaxters pra que.colocar índice no password e outra não vai estourar a hash é bem menor

Comment: @WallaceMaxters editei a resposta, e foi a maneira que solucionamos aqui, para não precisar toda hora ficar alterando o tamanho do campo string.

Comment: @arllondias eu resolvi o problema mudando de `utf8mb4` para um `utf8_*_ci` da vida.

Answer (score 2):

Eu resolvi esse problema trocando o `charset` e o `collation` nas configurações do bando de dados, em `config/database.php`:

```
//'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
//'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
'charset'   => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
```

Outra solução, já apresentada na outra pergunta, mas  pode ser feita globalmente ao invés de individualmente, é definir o tamanho máximo da string para `191`. Isso deverá ser feito no `AppServiceProvider::boot`.

```
Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
```

**Nota**: Não acho uma boa ideia usar a segunda opção, eu preferi trocar o `charset` e o `collation`.